# functional resembling random variable norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

Let $N\subset\mathbb{R}$ be finite
and define
$$
A(N)
=
\sum_{i
\in\mathbb{Z}
}\min\{
2
^i,
|N\cap[2^i,2^{i+1})|
\},
$$
where
$\mathbb{Z}=\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots\}$
and
$|\cdot|$ denotes set cardinality.

If $X\sim\mathrm{uniform}(N)$ is the corresponding random variable,
then $||X||_A:=A(N)$ acts as a quasi-norm of sorts. It appears to be homogeneous and nearly subadditive,
in the sense that
$
||X+Y||_A
\le
c(||X||_A+||Y||_A)$
for some universal $c>0$.

Question: Can $||X||_A$ be related to any classic norm of $X$? Probably not an $L_p$ norm, but perhaps an Orlicz norm? I'm mostly interested in upper-bounding $||X||_A$ by a classic random variable norm.

Update: What I said about homogeneity is incorrect: it appears to be "nearly" homogeneous
in the sense that
$
||\alpha X||_A
\le
c\alpha|| X||_A$
for some universal $c>0$.

Comment: Are you sure that what you wrote for negative $i$ in the definition of $A(N)$ is what you really meant?

Comment: Hi @fedja yes I think so... What do you think a more logical definition for $A(N)$ would be? I actually don't mind just summing over the non-negative $i$ but then you lose homogeneity.

Comment: So the negative part of $N$ is just ignored in the definition of $A(N)$ but not ignored in the definition of $X$? Or is $N$ contained in $(0,+\infty)$?